# Ошибка доступа к переменной класса.

Tags: delphi

```
type TGagGraph = class(Tobject)

      type ImageInfo = record
       width : integer;
       height:integer;
       srcDC,bufDC: hdc;
   end;

   var imgInf:imageinfo;
   procedure repaint_dc;
   constructor Create;     
 end;

                             implementation

    constructor TGagGraph.Create;
     begin
     imginf.width:=0;           // <------- Exception class EAccsesViolation with messgae 'Accses violation at adress 00435eaf in module re.exe'.
     end;

          //=============================
         var q: tgaggraph;
            begin
               q.create;
            end;
```

что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так определить класс + запись:

> ```
>         ImageInfo = record
>        width : integer;
>        height:integer;
>        srcDC,bufDC: hdc;
>    end;
>
>   type TGagGraph = class(Tobject)
>
>    imgInf:imageinfo;
>    procedure repaint_dc;
>    constructor Create;
>  end;
> ```

**И затем вызвать конструктор ТАК:**

> ```
> .....
> obj:TGagGraph;
> begin
> obj:=TGagGraph.Create;
> ....
> ```

У меня все работает !

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает на ура!

Comment: Незачто =)